# Flutter Http request avaible on broser but can't work on Android device

Tags: flutter

**[Solved] It's caused by my own network situation.If you are in China , don't forget to check your VPN.**

I want to use TheMovieDB api in my flutter project, but I can't get the response when I run it on my Android device.

- when I try to run it in browser , it works perfectly.
- just few minutes ago it works. But then it doesn't.

My code:

```
final url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=3c4cb870e3f3c729ef1eb2d0538ba4f7&language=en-US?page=$page";
try{
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  print(response);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print('json is:');
    print(json);
    result = json['results']; 
  } else {
    result =
    'Error getting IP address:\nHttp status ${response.statusCode}';
  }
}catch(e){
  print(e);
}
```

the error message is:

```
SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = api.themoviedb.org, port = 42230
```

Comment: Are you running on emulator or on real device?

Comment: I tried both of them.

Comment: That's weird I'm using your code and it's giving responses on chrome, emulator, and on a real device. Have you added the permission of internet in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: I can run it on my Edge too. And I add these to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: Switch off wifi reinstall app build again do these think. Do these check if something new happens.

Comment: I did all of this, and I'm going to start a new project to test these code.

Comment: And I failed. So confused.....

Comment: possible to share Github link?

Comment: Thank you! This my new project just for testing this problem  
 https://github.com/zodiacVG/bylens_testhttp

Comment: Oh....I just test another API and it seems good....  Damn, but why...

Comment: It is working for me.

Comment: Ok it seems i have to reform my environment. Thank you so much, thank you.

Comment: @DIACZ I m also facing same problem. Can you please tell me how did you get it work?

Answer (score -1):

Please check if you have provided the correct permissions and also if you have specified the right config on  your emulator

Comment: I have tried it on a real device, at first it works well, but then the problem appears. This is the real confusing thing.